# Inserting select JSON data into MySQLi

Tags: php, json

I am working with a json file for the very first time and I need to insert some of its data into a MySQLi table.
However, I need ONLY values in row1 and row5.
Below is the json tree and my feebleminded attempt.

```
{
    'category1':'value1',
    'category2':'
        [
            {
               'row1':'value2'
               'row2':'value3'
               'row3':'value4'
               'row4':'value5'
               'row5':'value6'
            },
            {
               'row1':'value7'
               'row2':'value8'
               'row3':'value9'
               'row4':'value10'
               'row5':'value11'
            },
                   (...) x100        
        ]
}

$json=file_get_contents('/*url of the json file*/');
$json_object=json_decode($json);

foreach($json_object->category2 as $json_object)
{
    $needed_value1=$json_object->category2->row1; /*This is where I think my attempt breaks*/  
    $needed_value2=$json_object->category2->row5; /*down but I have no idea how to proceed.*/

    $query=mysqli_prepare($connection,'INSERT INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)');  
    mysqli_bind_param($query,'ss',$needed_value1,$needed_value2);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
    mysqli_stmt_close($query);
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: $json_object->category2->row1 to $json_object->row1

Comment: If you're working for the first time, then divide your task in two: getting data from json and storing it in db

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty absolutely right! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Your Common Sense I made various edits to make it more clear and I was already sure the storing of the data was working fine. Maybe I should have been more explicit about that.

Comment: I don't want to sound nitpicking, but in fact, your title says "inserting something in mysql". You don't need to edit this one - just consider more adequate naming in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to validate your json to check whether it is valid or not.

To validate Json you can use jsonlint (http://jsonlint.com/)

Then suppose your json is like $x as below.

$x= '{
    "category1": "value1",
    "category2": [
        {
            "row1": "value2",
            "row2": "value3",
            "row3": "value4",
            "row4": "value5",
            "row5": "value6"
        },
        {
            "row1": "value2",
            "row2": "value3",
            "row3": "value4",
            "row4": "value5",
            "row5": "value6"
        }
    ]
}';

Decode your Json $x

$json_object=json_decode($x);

Loop through the decoded json then print your loop object "$json_object" from that object you can find your correct node of categories.

foreach($json_object->category2 as $json_object){

```
print_r($json_object);
echo $needed_value1 = $json_object->row1;
echo $needed_value2 = $json_object->row5;
echo $needed_value1 = $json_object->row1;

etc.....
```

}